# Can't run maven tests that include many projects

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit

I have many java projects, each with its maven build. They all `install` fine.

In addition, I have many JUnit tests. These tests may depend on other projects, i.e. a test from `Project A` may import a class from `Project B`.

My projects are not structered good (all of the classes are just in `src` directory and not `src/main/java`). So when I run `mvn clean test` I get `No sources to compile`. If I structure it good by moving all of the main classes to `src/main/java` and all the tests to `src/test/java` I keep getting `cannot find symbol` (with a reference to an import of a class in a different project).

I tried defining `<testSourceDirectory>`, used many different `plugins` and `profiles` and also tried lowering my java `configuration` level to 1.7, all to no avail.

I even tried defining a TestProject that has a simple POM with many modules (either with only `<modules>`, or defining `<dependencies>` or both), but even in this - either I get `No sources to compile`, `cannot find symbol` or even `package x.y does not exist` (or it compiles but trying to include it in other projects does nothing).

Can I run a test that involves classes from other other projects? How?

Comment: Could you post a pom of a project that includes a test and the pom of the project that the test depends on? This would make things clearer.

Comment: Do you need to depend on a test class or a source class from a different module?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can have and use Test dependencies. I'll explain how i achieve that, hope  it's usefull for your project.

I've got a project with many subprojects (named projectA, projectB, etc.) each one with its own Tests. Also one of the projects named 'core' with jar packaging that  contains common classes. They look like the following structure:

```
Main 
   |- core (jar)
   |- projectA (war)
   |- projectB (war)
```

All tests on the diferent projects used common code that finally were placed on 'core' project test clases.
This is how we manage the dependencies on maven 3.1.1.

Only for reference Main is also a project with its own pom.xml

Main (pom.xml):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.myproject</groupId>
  <artifactId>MyArtifact</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <properties>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
  </repositories>

  <modules>
    <module>core</module>
    <module>projectA</module>
    <module>projectB</module>
  </modules> 
   ...
</project>
```

On core project pom.xml we put:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>core</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<parent>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.myproject</groupId>
  <artifactId>MyArtifact</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</parent>
<build>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
    <!-- Common test classes jar creation -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>test-jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      ...
```

And on the rest of the projects pom.xml we put the dependency with this jar:

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- We put dependency with core.jar an test-core.jar -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.mycompany.myproject</groupId>
      <artifactId>core</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.mycompany.myproject</groupId>
      <artifactId>core</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <type>test-jar</type>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Eclipse warns about this maven dependency but it works fin when running Test from the command line with maven.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ran, has you tried my aproach? Does it fit your needs?

Comment: I will try it tomorrow, but tell me - by your structure it seems you have projects core, projctA and projectB, under Main. Is Main a project, or was it just to show me?

Comment: Thats Correct. Main is also a project with its own pom.cml. I'll update my answer to include it.